# Can I embed an jquery facebook multi-friend selector in a php iframe app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, multi-friend-selector

I've been wondering if there are any multi-friend selector similar to

http://mbrevoort.github.com/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector/

that can be used with php as I'm using PHP SDK. I've searched alot and most of the answers were to use fbml. But, Since facebook is deprecating fbml from Jan 1st 2012 I was looking for some solution to use with PHP SDK.

Thanks in advance

Prakash

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, not with PHP but JavaScript SDK. This have nothing to do with server-side of your application since "jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector" it only rely on Facebook JavaScript SDK and jQuery to work. Once you get the data from it you can pass it to server and use any technology you like to process this data (which may be PHP in your case)

Similar UI have Facebook Requests Dialog which may be used in some cases.